# Python-Remove empty list from dictionary from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains another dictionary that containst a list. I know it is a nightmare, but I use it in order to classify it properly.

```
L = {}
for s in range(N):
    L[s] = {}
    for a in A[s]:
        L[s][a] = []
        for i in x:
            if (whatever condition for i):
                L[s][a].append(i)
```

So, my problem is that this code creates a list for each a for each s. Then, if a certain condition is fulfiled then this list is fulled with elements. However, if this condition is not fulfiled, the list remains empty.
And this fact, the empty list, causes me serious problems in the following computations, therfore I need to remove that list.

To sum it up, I would need to get it from:

EDIT:

```
0: {0.0: [0.10000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004], 0.10000000000000001: []}, 1:...
```

to:

```
0: {0.0: [0.10000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004], 0.10000000000000001:}, 1:....
```

I there any way? I tried the `.remove()` and `del`, but I didn't work.

Comment: `{[]}` is a set containing a list, which is invalid because lists are not hashable. Can you clarify how original input looks?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Sorry, there was a mistake.

Comment: @Ajax1234 If it it not possible to remove the list, is it possible to remove the  key that stores that empty list?

Comment: please provide a [mcve], and take care to be explicit about your input and expected output.

Comment: So you have a dictionary of dictionaries keyed by floats valued by lists of floats, and you want to remove any key-value pairs in the inner dictionaries that have empty lists as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add only keys for lists that have content in the first place:

```
L = {}
for s in range(N):
    L[s] = {}
    for a in A[s]:
        for i in x:
            if (whatever condition for i):
                L[s].setdefault(a, []).append(i)  # new list only if there is content
```

No need to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to remove the key-value pair whose value is an empty list:

```
s = {0: {0.0: [0.10000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004], 0.10000000000000001: []}}
def new_s(s):
   return {a:(b if not isinstance(b, dict) else new_s(b)) for a, b in s.items() if b}
```

Output:

```
{0: {0.0: [0.1, 0.30000000000000004]}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this needs to be recursive. `{k1: {k2: v2 for k2, v2 in v1.items() if v2} for k1, v1 in your_dict.items()}`

Comment: @AdamSmith you are right, however, I think recursion in this case is cleaner than a nested dictionary comprehenion :)